# Calculate Time Tracking from log file

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a log file that stores login and logout of users session.my users are login and logout multiple time in a day. now i want to calculate how much time my user was online in each day or week.

this is a sample of my log file:

```
  DATE & Time   Status
1/25/2021 22:45 LOGIN
1/25/2021 7:49  LOGOUT
1/25/2021 4:16  LOGIN
1/25/2021 3:16  LOGOUT
1/24/2021 21:33 LOGIN
1/24/2021 7:38  LOGOUT
1/24/2021 5:37  LOGIN
1/24/2021 4:47  LOGOUT
1/24/2021 1:28  LOGIN
1/24/2021 1:23  LOGIN
1/23/2021 21:58 LOGIN
1/23/2021 13:09 LOGOUT
1/23/2021 11:41 LOGIN
1/23/2021 8:54  LOGOUT
1/23/2021 8:48  LOGIN
1/23/2021 5:54  LOGOUT
1/23/2021 1:06  LOGIN
1/22/2021 21:54 LOGIN
1/22/2021 21:53 LOGOUT
1/22/2021 21:46 LOGIN
```

[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvm9N.png)

is it possible to calculate online time in excel?

Best Regards.

i've attached my sample file (i converted it to xlsx)

https://www.sendspace.com/file/40rwg5

Comment: You have more ins than outs. What formula do you use to resolve that?

Comment: Where is user name column?

Comment: i didn't find any solution yet, i am not sure excel can resolve this problem.

Comment: date and time is one column name and status is another column.

Comment: I have similar solution, but it is done in Power Query. Let us know if PQ is possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula if the data meets some of the prerequisites:

1. Login / Logout must be in pairs
2. In terms of time Login must be before Logout
3. Login / Logout must be within a day

I edited your sample data to get correct result.

To get list of dates use array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INT($A$2:$A$21),MATCH(1,--(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,INT($A$2:$A$21))=0),0)),"")
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

to calculate hours use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$21*(D2=INT($A$2:$A$21))*("logout"=$B$2:$B$21)-$A$2:$A$21*(D2=INT($A$2:$A$21))*("login"=$B$2:$B$21))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. when i use array formula for list of dates, i got nothing. may i ask you to help me how can i use this formula?

Comment: Do you enter it with ctrl + shift + enter? Is dates in ```Date&Time``` column true dates or text?

Comment: Formatting the cell will not help. You can check if it is a date with the formula ```=ISNUMBER(A2)```. If ```TRUE``` is returned, then ```A2``` is the date, if ```FALSE```, then the text.

Comment: [Shared file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yQAJOLgXeAuigmDKWnoJ63zT8-oC0wxP/view?usp=sharing) @FarhadBarati

Comment: thanks, when i open sample file in my excel, i got ######## in some hours column.
https://www.sendspace.com/file/m89sby

Comment: is it possible to remove AM from Hours column?

Comment: @FarhadBarati you get #### for negative hours. If you can not comply with the prerequisites, you will not be able to calculate the hours correctly. To remove ```AM``` from hours column use custom format - ```[hh]:mm```